# ubuntu 20.04.1 in hp laptop boot at grub command line everytime

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, hp

Installed ubuntu 20.04 and every time I turn on the machine it starts on grub command line mode.then I have to type "exit" and select the right disk to boot from(which is "Notebook Hard drive".it works this way.
I have tried to edit BIOS setting and put "Notebook Hard drive" in first place ,it didn't work.
My device is hp notebook,in which both uefi and legacy mode is enabled for boot.

I also have installed boot repair from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

this is the diagnostic result https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bg6QY2S4qk/

Comment: You might want to describe your installation procedure to help others understand the cause of your issue. Alsp your patse.ubuntu link say `The Paste you are looking for does not currently exist.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstalling grub solved my problem. link below for how to reinstall grub
https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today on a Thinkpad w540... for reasons unknown every time I tried booting it went to the grub prompt.  Finally in frustration I removed the battery. about an hour later I put the battery back in and it booted up just fine

Comment: This is really weird for a solution... lol.

Answer (score 0):

For those who manually partition your disk, you need to make sure [EFI system partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) exists before clicking the button `install now` , otherwise you may end up hitting the GRUB command line interface after installation. [this article](https://www.itzgeek.com/post/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-lts/#step-6-create-partitions) describes how to set up the partitions.